# How to mint when using the ERC721A contract (address, tokenid)?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, erc-721

ERC721A's mint function is

```
  function _safeMint(address to, uint256 quantity) internal {
    _safeMint(to, quantity, "");
  }
```

is it possible to mint with address and tokenId?

Answer (score 0):

No, from their docs: "Assumes serials are sequentially minted starting at _startTokenId() (defaults to 0, e.g. 0, 1, 2, 3..)."

See https://github.com/chiru-labs/ERC721A/blob/main/contracts/ERC721A.sol#L18